# Getting undefined identifier error for already defined identifier in windows forms c++/cli program

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, boost, c++-cli, boost-graph

I am not quite sure why the edge_array that is created is being shown as a undefined identifier when being used in the button click handler I am new to cli/c++ silly mistakes will be a likely cause on further note I am using VS2010 and I am also using boost unmanaged code in the mix of the cli managed stuff any help will be much appreciated

```cpp
namespace Prototype {
    //using namespace boost;
    using namespace boost::graph;
    using namespace boost::numeric::ublas;
    using namespace System;
    using namespace System::ComponentModel;
    using namespace System::Collections;
    using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
    using namespace System::Data;
    using namespace System::Drawing;
    using namespace System::Runtime::InteropServices;
    using namespace msclr::interop;

    /// <summary>
    /// Summary for Form1
    /// </summary>
    //graph properties types
    typedef boost::property<boost::edge_weight_t, double> EdgeWeightProperty;
    typedef boost::property<boost::vertex_name_t, std::string, boost::property<boost::vertex_potential_t, int, boost::property<boost::vertex_update_t, double> > > StationProperties;

    //graph type
    typedef boost::adjacency_list<boost::vecS, boost::vecS, boost::directedS, StationProperties, EdgeWeightProperty> Graph;

    //instantiation
    Graph g;

    // Property accessors
    boost::property_map<Graph, boost::vertex_name_t>::type station_name = get(boost::vertex_name, g);
    boost::property_map<Graph, boost::vertex_potential_t>::type station_capacity = get(boost::vertex_potential, g);
    boost::property_map<Graph, boost::vertex_update_t>::type station_update = get(boost::vertex_update, g);
    boost::property_map<Graph, boost::edge_weight_t>::type edge_distance = get(boost::edge_weight, g);

    //vertex descriptor
    typedef boost::graph_traits<Graph>::vertex_descriptor Vertex;

    //transition matrix definition and station vector definition
    matrix<double> trans(6,6);
    vector<double> stat(6);

    bool inserted;
    int counter = 0;

    typedef boost::graph_traits<Graph>::edge_descriptor edge_descriptor;

    edge_descriptor e;

    public ref class Form1 : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
    {
    public:
        Form1(void)
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            //station vector definition
            stat(0) = 1000;
            stat(1) = 1000;
            stat(2) = 1000;
            stat(3) = 1000;
            stat(4) = 1000;
            stat(5) = 1000;

            //transition matrix
            trans(0,0) = 0; trans(0,1) = 1; trans(0,2) = 0; trans(0,3) = 0; trans(0,4) = 0; trans(0,5) = 0;
            trans(1,0) = 0.25; trans(1,1) = 0; trans(1,2) = 0.75; trans(1,3) = 0; trans(1,4) = 0; trans(1,5) = 0;
            trans(2,0) = 0; trans(2,1) = 0.33; trans(2,2) = 0; trans(2,3) = 0.33; trans(2,4) = 0.33; trans(2,5) = 0;
            trans(3,0) = 0; trans(3,1) = 0; trans(3,2) = 0.75; trans(3,3) = 0; trans(3,4) = 0; trans(3,5) = 0.25;
            trans(4,0) = 0; trans(4,1) = 0; trans(4,2) = 0.75; trans(4,3) = 0; trans(4,4) = 0; trans(4,5) = 0.25;
            trans(5,0) = 0; trans(5,1) = 0; trans(5,2) = 0; trans(5,3) = 0.5; trans(5,4) = 0.5; trans(5,5) = 0;

            //station graph declerations

            Vertex u0;
            u0 = add_vertex(g);
            station_name[u0] = "Kennington";
            station_capacity[u0] = 2000;
            station_update[u0] = stat(0);

            Vertex u1;
            u1 = add_vertex(g);
            station_name[u1] = "Elephant & Castle";
            station_capacity[u1] = 2000;
            station_update[u1] = stat(1);

            Vertex u2;
            u2 = add_vertex(g);
            station_name[u2] = "London Bridge";
            station_capacity[u2] = 3000;
            station_update[u2] = stat(2);

            Vertex u3;
            u3 = add_vertex(g);
            station_name[u3] = "Bank";
            station_capacity[u3] = 3000;
            station_update[u3] = stat(3);

            Vertex u4;
            u4 = add_vertex(g);
            station_name[u4] = "Borough";
            station_capacity[u4] = 2000;
            station_update[u4] = stat(4);

            Vertex u5;
            u5 = add_vertex(g);
            station_name[u5] = "Oval";
            station_capacity[u5] = 3000;
            station_update[u5] = stat(5);

            typedef std::pair<int,int> Edge;
            Edge edge_array[] = {
                Edge(u0, u0), Edge(u0, u1),Edge(u0, u2),Edge(u0, u3),Edge(u0, u4),Edge(u0, u5),
                Edge(u1, u0), Edge(u1, u1),Edge(u1, u2),Edge(u1, u3),Edge(u1, u4),Edge(u1, u5),
                Edge(u2, u0), Edge(u2, u1),Edge(u2, u2),Edge(u2, u3),Edge(u2, u4),Edge(u2, u5),
                Edge(u3, u0), Edge(u3, u1),Edge(u3, u2),Edge(u3, u3),Edge(u3, u4),Edge(u3, u5),
                Edge(u4, u0), Edge(u4, u1),Edge(u4, u2),Edge(u4, u3),Edge(u4, u4),Edge(u4, u5),
                Edge(u5, u0), Edge(u5, u1),Edge(u5, u2),Edge(u5, u3),Edge(u5, u4),Edge(u5, u5)
            };
        //all other declerations

    private:
        void Build_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
            //station_name[u0] = marshal_as<std::string> (this->NameBox0->Text);
            station_name[0] = marshal_as<std::string> (this->NameBox0->Text);
            station_name[1] = marshal_as<std::string> (this->NameBox1->Text);
            station_name[2] = marshal_as<std::string> (this->NameBox2->Text);
            station_name[3] = marshal_as<std::string> (this->NameBox3->Text);
            station_name[4] = marshal_as<std::string> (this->NameBox4->Text);
            station_name[5] = marshal_as<std::string> (this->NameBox5->Text);

            station_capacity[0] = System::Convert::ToInt32(this->Capbox0->Text);
            station_capacity[1] = System::Convert::ToInt32(this->Capbox1->Text);
            station_capacity[2] = System::Convert::ToInt32(this->Capbox1->Text);
            station_capacity[3] = System::Convert::ToInt32(this->Capbox1->Text);
            station_capacity[4] = System::Convert::ToInt32(this->Capbox1->Text);
            station_capacity[5] = System::Convert::ToInt32(this->Capbox5->Text);

            for (unsigned i = 0; i < trans.size1 (); ++ i){
                for (unsigned j = 0; j < trans.size2 (); ++ j){
                    if (trans(i,j) > 0.1)
                    {
                        boost::tie(e, inserted) = boost::add_edge(edge_array[counter].first,edge_array[counter].second,g);
                        edge_distance[e] = trans(i,j);
                    }
                    ++counter;
                }
            }
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are both declaring and initialising the edge_array within the Form1 constructor.  Since you declare the variable within the scope of Form1() it only exists within the scope of Form1().

Outside of Form1() edge_array is undefined.

To make edge_array visible to Button_Click you need to declare it outside the class like `vector<double> stat` is declared or declare it within the class like other class member variables - somewhere in the `//all other declerations` area.

You can still initialise the array within the constructor.